# If I (a non-Teams admin) create a Slack notification, is it supposed to be visible to everyone on the Team?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, slack

I'm looking for some general information about how the Slack integration works in a Team.

On Friday I created a Slack account and, because I was curious and had nothing else to do with it, I decided to use the notifications feature on the Team I use to get notifications in Slack if I'm pinged in the Team. It was mostly a "for science" thing as I don't use Slack and I'm more likely to see pings on SE directly...

That said, over the weekend, someone asked me what my Slack integration was for  on the Team. I'll admit that I was surprised that anyone could even see it, let alone that I'd created it. I'm not a Team admin, so I wasn't expecting *my* Slack notifications setup to be *the* Slack integration for the Team... or is this just not working correctly? No one else on my Team has access to my Slack workspace but there doesn't really seem to be any documentation I could find about the Slack integration.

Someone else mentioned that they almost deleted it. Is that even possible? If they had, what would have happened to my notifications?

Are the other members of the Team *supposed* to see my own (personal?) Slack integration?

Is using Slack for notifications the *only* form of integration at this point?

Comment: I've added a full breakdown of how visibility of notifications works below - I'm guessing that in your case it was either an Admin who saw it OR you were posting to a public channel on your own Slack Workspace.

Comment: PS: We'll also be posting this breakdown on the [Stack Overflow for Teams Help Center](https://stackoverflow.help) for future reference.

Comment: After figuring out how to even tell whether the channel is public or private, I can confirm that it is public. The user I was talking with wasn't an Admin. :) Thanks! Help pages are really useful! A link to that on the integrations page would really be useful, I think.

Comment: Does this mean that a *non-admin* of a Team can create Slack notifications for any Slack channel, potentially exposing the private content of the Team to a possibly unrelated Slack channel?

Answer (score 8):

**Viewing Slack Integrations For Your Teams**

Slack notifications for your Teams can be viewed and configured by going to the "Edit Profile and Settings" tab of your user profile and selecting the "Slack" button (`/users/integrations/slack/`).

**How Visibility Works**

Configured Slack integrations for Teams have different visibility to the Team depending on whether they are configured to post to public or private Slack channels:

In the case of posting to ***public*** Slack channels (those viewable to any member of your Slack Workspace) - then any member of your Stack Overflow Team can see that integration and modify it.  The idea is that if it's a general company chat channel, it's not *your* integration so much as the *team's* integration that you set up and any member of the Team should be able to configure it.

In the case of posting to ***private*** Slack channels (or Slack DMs/Private Messages), those integrations are only visible to the user who created them.

**Admins & Visibility**

In addition to having the same view on their profile/settings page as other users, Team Admins also have the ability to see and manage ***all*** active Slack integrations for their team via the admin panel (`/admin/integrations/slack`).  This includes postings to both private or public channels in your Slack Workspace.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I think the only part I'm still not sure about is what would happen if someone (a non-Admin) deleted the Slack integration?

Comment: @Catija then it would be deleted and someone would have to make a new one for that Channel if they wanted it back.

Comment: My guess is that it would go away since if an employee was fired or put the integration into a channel that caused it to overrun the regular users, it would be helpful to be able to stop it.

Comment: Doesn't it seem a bit odd to let *anyone* do that - delete my ability to get notifications? Would I even be notified if that happened? Seems like something better limited to an Admin? I'm not sure I understand why any user can add a Slack integration that *everyone* can see in the first place... as I said in the question, I really wasn't expecting it. I know that Charcoal is an odd Team... so maybe it's irrelevant but it ... dunno. Not what I would expect :D